# Domain mapping with Multisite links are wrong

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have multisite setup and I'm using the `WordPress MU Domain Mapping` plugin so I can control other domains with multisite. I have it installed on a subdomain to act as my command location. I plan to connect main sites and staging sites:

- maindev.site1.com (mutlisite install)
- dev.site1.com
- site1.com
- dev.site2.com
- site2.com
- etc

because I'm installed in a subdomain and the way the hosting works my multisite is subdirectory based so `dev.site1.com` is actually `maindev.site1.com/dev`.

The issue instead of links being `dev.site1.com/hello-world` they are `maindev.site1.com/dev/hello-world`. Both work but the links are correct. I've tried reseting permalinks but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out right after I posted the question but thought it would help someone who ran into the same issue. I have to go to:

Network Admin -> Sites -> edit a site -> Settings -> change "site url" and "home"